# Android sqlite table into json Array

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have SQLite database contains one table. In the table, I have five fields. For example
id, name, question, year, answer.That convert jsonArray.

I tried my code given below which return only one column.

```
      try{
          JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
                JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
                    if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                        try {
                            if (cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                                Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i));
                                rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                            } else {
                                rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                jArray.put(rowObject);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
            Log.d("jsonA", jArray.toString());
```

The Above code  result is
                  [{id:"1"}{  id:"2"}
                                                       ]

I want return five row and their value in jsonArray

```
[{"id":"1", "name":"sh", "question":"yid", "year":"uyit", "answer":"uify"},
 {"id":"2","name":"sh","question":"syusyuytu","year":"uysrtuy","answer":"sturt"} ]
```

My Cursor query

```
public Cursor listoftest() {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("list_of_question_set", new String[]{ "id","name","description","questions","duration","correct","negative"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: do you have any exception?

Comment: NO    EXCEPTION  WHEN I TRIED CODE

Comment: can you update the query from which you are getting the cursor?

Comment: i have update the query

Comment: you are querying the columns different from your expected results. year and answer are not present in your query columns

Comment: ok thank but the given sample code. the query i done mistake thanks for answer

Comment: please accept my answer below if this resolved your problem @Jayapriya

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

> Declare One Arraylist

```
  ArrayList<DataPojaClass > alUser = new ArrayList<>();
```

try{

```
 ArrayList<DataPojaClass > alUser = new ArrayList<>();



    JSONArray parentArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray();

    for (int j = 0; j < parentArray.length(); j++) {

        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);
        // User
        DataPojaClass user = new DataPojaClass ();
        // Set user values
        user.setId(finalObject.getString("id"));

        user.setName(finalObject.getString("name"));

        user.setQuestion(finalObject.getString("question"));

        user.setYear(finalObject.getString("year"));


        alUser.add(user);
    }
    // Finally return user list
    dataset.addAll(alUser)
}
}catch(Exception E){
```

}

** Create DataPojaClass Class**

```
 public class DataPojaClass
{
    private  String id;
    private  String name;
    private  String question;
    private  String year;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    private  String answer;
}
```

Comment: I ASKED HOW TO RETIVE DATA FROM SQLITE AND PUT INTO JSON ARRAY

Answer (score 1):

Your query for cursor does not matches the expected output. year and answer are not present in your query columns

```
 public Cursor listoftest() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("list_of_question_set", new String[]{ "id","name","description","questions","duration","correct","negative"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
   return cursor;
}
```

and your expected output is

```
[{id:"1"name:"sh",question:"yid",year:"uyit",answer:"uify"}
{  id:"2"name:"sh",question:"syusyuytu",year:"uysrtuy",answer:"sturt"} ]
```

you need to resolve the conflict

Comment: you need to accept the answer by clicking the  tick button on the left side of the answer below upvote and  downvote button @Jayapriya

Comment: ya but i need 15k repution to public vote i will gain i will accept it